# Insertion of over-specific detail to humorous effect

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, humor, rhetorical-devices

In *Gilmore Girls*, describing a debutante ball:
"It's like animals being up for bid at the county fair, except sheep don't wear hoop skirts."

This kind of over-the-top, facetious detail is used throughout the show and fuels the witty dialogue. Is there a word for humor created by such an unexpected, specific detail?

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237068/what-is-it-called-when-someone-uses-a-slightly-absurd-specific-example-of-someth/237087) suggests "facetious synecdoche," but I don't think the example above is synecdoche (except for "sheep" being representative of "animals", but it's really the "hoop skirts" that drives the humor). I'm also not looking for: "detail," "imagery," "satire," "hyperbole."

Comment: +1 nice, very nice question. It's hard to believe that you're a new user.

Comment: its saying girls are animals

Answer (score 5):

In comedy, this is called [*tagging a joke*](http://www.creatingacomic.com/comedy-glossary/). The *tag* is a following reference to the punchline that adds comedic effect. Here the (supposedly) amusing punch is the comparison of debutantes at a ball to farm animals to be judged at a fair. The tag is the mention by denial of hoop skirts on sheep, which attire is suitable only for debutantes, i.e., neither for sheep nor for reasonable women.